# Kernel module linked list strange behaviour

Tags: c, kernel

I am creating a linked list in kernel module ; It has no problem with adding the first record , in init module i am initializing the map also with create map function ;

```
typedef struct IP4SYN{    
    unsigned int KaynakIP;
    u_int16_t KaynakPort;
    u_int16_t HedefPort;
} IP4SYN;

typedef struct IP4Map{
    unsigned int HedefIP;
    IP4SYN * a;
    size_t s;
    size_t n;
} IP4Map;

typedef struct Sessions{
    IP4Map * a;
    size_t s;
    size_t n;
} Sessions;
static size_t blocksize = (1024*102);

Sessions * Session_Map;

static unsigned int get_tsval(void){    
    return (unsigned int)(ktime_to_ns(ktime_get())>>10);
}
Sessions * CreateMap(size_t initial){
    Sessions * pMap = (Sessions *)vmalloc(sizeof(Sessions));
    if (initial > 0 && blocksize != initial) {
        blocksize = initial;
    }
    pMap->a = (IP4Map *)vmalloc(sizeof(IP4Map)*blocksize);
    memset(pMap->a, 0, sizeof(IP4Map)*blocksize);
    pMap->s = blocksize;  
    pMap->n = 0;  

    pMap->a->a=(IP4SYN *)vmalloc(sizeof(IP4SYN)*blocksize);
    memset(pMap->a->a, 0, sizeof(IP4SYN)*blocksize);
    pMap->a->s = blocksize;  
    pMap->a->n = 0;  
    return pMap;   
}
size_t HedefIPKayitNo(unsigned int HedefIP){
    size_t beg = 0; 
    size_t end = Session_Map->n;
    for (beg; beg < end; beg) {
        IP4Map map = Session_Map->a[beg];
        if(map.HedefIP==HedefIP){
            return beg;
            break;
        }
    }
    return beg;
}   
size_t YeniHedefIP(unsigned int HedefIP,size_t index){
    Session_Map->a[index].HedefIP = HedefIP;
    Session_Map->n++;
}
```

I want to check if ip exist in listed and if not listed i want to add it to the list. But strangely it causing lack of kernel on 2nd try . 1st add-up is working perfect. what should be the issue ?

```
size_t IP_Index = HedefIPKayitNo(hedef_ip);
        if(IP_Index == Session_Map->n ){
                YeniHedefIP(hedef_ip,(IP_Index));

}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a linked list? It's just a dynamically allocated array. In your implementation of insertion, `YeniHedefIP`, the `index` can only sensible be the length of the array, otherwise you will overwrite the item at the index and add a garbage item at the end. You should also check whether the array overflows.

Comment: `for (beg; beg < end; beg)` -- What's that? Surely that should be something like `for (beg = 0; beg < end; beg++)`, otherwise you'll get an infinite loop. (Your compiler should warn you about the `beg` without effect in the update section.)

Comment: Hello , thank you for the answers . beg & end is just loop into array to find the id of the sended ip address
I am sorry oehm you are correct , but i am not able to add second ip to list what should be the problem

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want to achieve. Your blocksize i roughly 1 million. (I guess `1024*102` is a typo?) Then you allocate 1 million IP4Maps, and then you initialize only the first with another 1 million IP4Syns. Then you talk about linked lists where ther are none. All that feels wrong.

Comment: Actually i know there is a mistake there ;
I want to create an allocation for thousand ip4 map  and each ip4map struct will have one thousand ip4syn struct.

Comment: I am sorry @MOehm now i realize beg++ issue but not solved :(